# AppStoreConnect Screenshot error asking for upload ipad screenshot while app is designed for iphone only. App is built in Xamarin ios

Tags: iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, upload, app-store-connect

I set device family to Iphone/iPod only in info.plist file  and when i upload app on app store it shows **Your  binary is designed for iPad Pro. Upload iPad Pro screenshots for a better App Store experience**. I restrict app for iPad then why still asking for add iPad screenshot on AppStoreConnect ?[see AppStoreConnect screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynWaq.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge even if you have selected iPhone/iPod device family, Apple expects that your app should get installed on iPad also that's why they are asking for iPad Pro screenshots, it is mandatory to provide iPad pro screenshots. But it is okay if your app design doesn't support iPad screen resolutions. Please refer the following URL to get a more detailed explanation on this:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301125/can-i-submit-an-app-without-ipad-version-to-app-store

**Please note**:
The explanation given in the above link is about native iOS apps but App-Store-Connect considers Xamarin.iOS also as a Native iOS app.

Comment: I forget to select the latest build version in which I restrict the app to install on iPad and then the issue is resolved.